# Add RawContact so it aggregates to an existing contact

Tags: android, contacts, aggregation, rawcontacts

I am trying to add a new RawContact to an existing Contact so my custom data field shows up inside the original Contact. I tried Adding a StructuredName Data row to my new RawContact with a DisplayName that matches the DisplayName of the original RawContact. I thought matching DisplayNames would be enough to aggregate both RawContacts but the contacts app seems to display both RawContacts as different Contacts.

Here is my code

```
  public static void addContact(Context context, Account account, String number, String displayname) {
    Log.e(Global.TAG, "adding contact: " + number + " / " + displayname);

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    //Create our RawContact
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);

    operationList.add(builder.build());

    //Create a Data record of common type 'StructuredName' for our RawContact
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayname);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    //Create a Data record of custom type "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.be.ourservice.profile" to display a link to the     profile
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.be.ourservice.profile");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, number);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "ourservice user");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Go to ourservice profile");
    operationList.add(builder.build());



    try {
     mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
     Log.d(Global.TAG, "addContact batch applied");
    } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(Global.TAG, "Something went wrong during creation! " + e);
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out. I tried replacing the CommonDataKinds.StructuredName row with a CommonDataKinds.Phone row that contains the same number as my original contact and then it aggregates the RawContacts correctly.

The working code looks like this

```
public static void addContactTag(Context context, Account account, String number) {

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    //  Create our RawContact                                                                                                           
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    //  Create a Data record of common type 'Phone' for our RawContact                                                                  
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
    operationList.add(builder.build());

    //Create a Data record of custom type "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.be.ourservice.profile" to display a link to our     profile    
    builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, OURSERVICE_MIMETYPE);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, number);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "ourservice user");
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Go to ourservice profile");
    operationList.add(builder.build());


    try {
        mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
        Log.d(Global.TAG, "addContact batch applied");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Global.TAG, "Something went wrong during creation! " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I think there should be a better way! based on google documentation, raw contact items with the same Raw.Contact_id aggregate into one contact, I've tried this, but it's not working :|

Comment: @Sirlate As per [the RawContacts documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html), that field is read-only.

Comment: where you add displayname