# Update contact pictures - support other providers like outlook

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

The code at the bottom shows how I update contact pictures from my app. This works well, if the user uses sim, phone and google contacts and similar. But if he uses the outlook app, the outlook app does overwrite the images set by my app again after some time.

Can I somehow solve that? Can I force to overwrite the outlook image as well so that outlook syncs my new photo instead of their old one?

**Code**

```
byte[] photo = ImageUtil.convertImageToByteArray(bitmap, true);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
int photoId = -1;
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " == " +
        contact.getRawId() + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=='" +
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
Cursor cursor = MainApp.get().getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        where,
        null,
        null);
int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Data._ID);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    photoId = cursor.getInt(idIdx);
}
cursor.close();
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contact.getRawId());
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo);
values.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

if (photoId >= 0) {
    MainApp.get().getContentResolver().update(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            values,
            ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = " + photoId, null);
} else {
    MainApp.get().getContentResolver().insert(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            values);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `SyncAdapters` has a configuration called `supportsUploading` set to either true or false.
You shouldn't modify RawContacts of accounts there were synced by a SyncAdapter with supportsUploading set to false, as most likely your change will probably get overwritten by the SyncAdapter soon after.

You can check the `supportsUploading` value of all `SyncAdapters` using the following code:

```
final SyncAdapterType[] syncs = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
for (SyncAdapterType sync : syncs) {
    Log.d(TAG, "found SyncAdapter: " + sync.accountType);
    if (ContactsContract.AUTHORITY.equals(sync.authority)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SyncAdapter supports contacts: " + sync.accountType + " - supportsUploading=" + sync.supportsUploading());
    }
}
```

In order to set a different pic to a contact synced by a read-only SyncAdapter, you can create a new RawContact under your own account ([preferably under your own SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)) and [join that new RawContact with the existing RawContact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419305/how-do-you-get-contacts-to-aggregate-properly-when-programmatically-adding-them) created by Outlook, then you can set SUPER_PRIMARY on your own picture, so it'll be the default one.

Comment: What will happen if another app does the same - adding it's own sync adapter and setting it's own contacts as super primary? Nevertheless, your suggestion makes sense and seems to solve the issue and escribes very well why I have issues and why those only happen rarely, especially in combination with outlook...