# Android ContactsContract class: How to ignore non-primary ACCOUNT_TYPES?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

So I know by now that I can use `ContactsContract` class to list all contacts available on an android device. Something like this:

```
private void getContacts(){

ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);

while(cursor.moveToNext){

//get contact id
.....
//get contact name
....

}

}
```

**What do I mean by `contact` above:**

A `contact` according to my understanding is a set of `raw_contacts`. Example:

These are 2 `contacts` in the phone book:

```
[ User A  ]
----------- 
[ User B  ]
```

Upon clicking User A I will get  this:

```
   | User A                                             |
   | phone 1: 0000 mobile                               | 
   | phone 2: 1111 home                                 |
   | phone 3: 2222 work                                 |
   |                                                    |
   |        linked :google , sim, phone, viber, whatsapp|
```

**From my understanding:**

- Contacts = User A or User B.
- raw_contacts = User A (phone) or User A (SIM) or User A (google) or User A (viber)....

**My question is:**

If I looped through all `contacts` and then looped through all `raw_contacts` in a `contact` **keeping in mind that raw_contacts can be alot**, and then looped through phone number (home, mobile, work...) of each raw contact...Then wouldn't it be bad for performance?

What should I do to only loop through mobile numbers that are stored on phone (sim, or device) without having to loop through `raw_contacts` that are generated by custom apps?

It makes no sense to loop through all `raw_contacts`.

Apps like whatsapp or viber or telegram or any phone app get these contacts fast and efficiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...Then wouldn't it be bad for performance?

Definitely bad performance.

> What should I do to only loop through mobile numbers?

Iterate directly over the `ContactsContract.Data` table, to get all phones from all RawContacts.

> Apps like whatsapp or viber or telegram or any phone app get these
>   contacts fast and efficiently.

This is partially false, it *seems* like it's super-fast because those app run a service to query for contacts, communicate with the server, and then cache results locally. Then they only need to query periodically for the delta (contacts added/removed). Even with the faster code below, run this in a background thread, as it may take time to run depending on the number of contacts on the device.

Sample code:

```
private class ContactInfo {
    public long id;
    public String name;
    Set<String> phones = new HashSet<>();

    public ContactInfo(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Map<Long, ContactInfo> contacts = new HashMap<Long, ContactInfo>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.DATA1};

// limit data results to just phone numbers.
// Note: you can potentially restrict the query to just phone & SIM contacts,
// but that would actually make the query slower not faster, because you'll need multiple queries over the DB, 
// instead of just a big one.
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String data = cur.getString(2); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234

    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + data;

    // add found phone to existing ContactInfo, or create a new ContactInfo object
    ContactInfo info;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        info = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        info = new ContactInfo(id, name);
        contacts.put(id, info);
    }
    info.phones.add(data);
}
cur.close();

// you now have a mapping between contact-id to an info object containing id, name, and a list of phone-numbers!
```

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate it, **question**: When looping through Data do I get every possible number attached to a contact id via (SIM, phone, device,google, ...)? And is the contact id unique? Also when I get the set of numbers would there be duplicate numbers?

Comment: (1) since i'm using a `Map` for `contacts` the key (contact-id) would be unique (2) since i'm using a `Set` for `phones` the numbers would be unique as well, but there may be duplicates with different formats, e.g. "+1-212-5555" & "212-5555". you can avoid those by converting all phones to the e164 format before adding them to `phones`

Comment: So we have a contact_id with a set of phones, now when checking with my server I must check if there is numbers on the server, in case of duplicates when I check for them in the server and add them to the local cache I will be adding 2 or maybe even 3 numbers to the same contact?

Comment: example: In whatsapp if a contact has multiple numbers (mobile, home, ...) and all these numbers exist in whatsapp server then whatsapp will show them in your contacts as the same contact, but they will add Moblie, Home, or Work beside the number.......But if these numbers are the same number meaning duplicates whatsapp will ignore them.......but anyway how is whatsapp pushing the numbers in the local database if they refer to the same unique contact id.....why HOME, WORK , MOBILE in whatsapp are not overwritten if they refer to same contact id?

Comment: i think you're extending way over your original question, all these questions are implementation specific, you can store local cache, or send things to your server however you want, you can store multiple numbers per contact if you want, and you can remove duplicates if you want, it's just a matter of selecting the right collection and DB solution

Comment: Yes true the question is extended...I was trying to understand how this ContractContact api works, because it has too many stuff and a bit complicated.....Thanks any way for your help and support.