# Android Contacts Contract: Is it possible to get unique id of data row?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

So I know by now that Contacts are saved in three tables:

- Contacts table.
- Raw contacts table.
- Data table.

**The table that I am using:**

I am using the data table to read users with all their phone numbers according to and thanks to @marmor in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954469/android-contactscontract-class-how-to-ignore-non-primary-account-types).

**What I got from the solution in the above link:**

Using the answer provided by @marmor in the above link I was able to query (for all contacts in the phonebook) a `contact_id` mapped to a `set of phone numbers` for this specific contact.

**Defining contact_id & set of phone numbers:**

- `contact_id`: Is the id of a contact in the phone book that can contain multiple types of linked accounts.
- `set of phone numbers`: Is a set containing all phone numbers of a specific contact_id.

### Problem:

Let's say I have two users X and Y :

user x has a contact_id = 0.

user y has a contact_id = 1.

Now let's say user x has these numbers linked: +1111-xxx and +2222-xxx

And let's say user y has these numbers linked: +3333-xxx and +2222-xxx

Now I decide to save all these numbers to the local database on the phone:

**case 1:**

If I used the numbers of these users as the main id to save into database then +2222-xxx in user x will overwrite +2222-xxx in user y.

**case 2:**

If I used the contact_id as the main id to save into database then +1111-xxx and +2222-xxx that corresponds to the same user_id (0) will both be overwritten so one will win.

**case 3:**

If used a combination of phone number + contact_id as the main id to save into database then as it might work it seems not the very clean solution and not stable.

**Question:**

Is it possible to get a unique id that identifies each number found in the contact_id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A. It is definitely possible to get a Data row id:**

When querying over Data.CONTENT_URI, just add Data._ID to your projection, and you can then get the specific Data ID and do whatever you want with it.

**B. Is it wise to persist the Data ID into your DB as the key of a contact/number combo? No.**

Data IDs can change over time, and are not guaranteed to be consistent, so it's highly discouraged to persist it into a local DB, and use it as a long-running identifier.

**C. What you can do instead?**

Use the E164 phone number as your key, as this is something static that can't change, a contact may gain or lose a phone number with its contact info, but the phone number is still the same phone number.

Just allow a one-to-many connection between your key - the phone number - and the contacts.
So a single phone number X can point to 0 or more different contacts that **currently** have that number in their data rows.

You'll need to run periodically (e.g. once a day) to refresh your internal DB with changes from the device's contacts DB.

Comment: Thanks as usual for your clear answer, but if I used the e 164 numbers as the key. Then if 2 users in the phone book (user a and user b) have the same number, then when saved to the database the numbers of both users will overwrite each other because they are the same.

Comment: "Just allow a one-to-many connection between your key - the phone number - and the contacts. So a single phone number X can point to 0 or more different contacts"

Comment: Do you mean to make the key a combination of (e 164 number + contact name)?